# Invalid value exception when calling findOne() with "where" option in Seqelize

Tags: nestjs, sequelize-typescript

**Project details**
using NestJs framework with Sequelize library for ORM and Postgres as a database

**Code details**

i have a pipe class that acts like a **validator** for the uniqueness of the phone number in the request body where it tries to fetch the user's record corresponding to the supplied phone number
like this instruction:

```js
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User)
    private readonly userModel: typeof User
  ) {}

    const user = await this.userModel.findOne({
      where: { phone }
    });
```

**Problem**

i get this error in the console when executing the validator:

> [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid value { phone: '+somePhoneNumber' }

sequelize library has one example of using `findOne()` method and it's as noted in the question here.

**Edited**

here is the phone attribute in user model:

```js
  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false
  })
  phone: string;
```

Comment: You should provide User model's code as well, seems like a type issue, I mean you may be declare phone as number in User's schema

Comment: i have updated the question for your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the object passed to `where` clause is actually an object of the shape `{phone: '+somePhoneNumber'}` which is invalid, it should be

```
const user = await this.userModel.findOne({
  where: { phone: data.phone }
});
```

`data` is the data passed to the pipe transform function, in my case & for nestjs developer it's the DTO of the current endppoint.